# SQL Text Matching Query Tuning

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do some free text search matching, and wondering if I can improve this query (using MSSQL 2008):

@FreeText is a table, where each row is a search word

```
DECLARE @WordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) from @FreeText)

SELECT p.ID
FROM Product p

OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(ID) as MatchCount
    FROM Product pm
    INNER JOIN @FreeText ft
    ON pm.txt like '%'+ft.text+'%'
    WHERE pm.ID = p.ID
    AND (SELECT TOP 1 [text] FROM @FreeText) IS NOT NULL
)MC

WHERE MatchCount = @WordCount
```

So I'm wondering if there is any way to avoid the "`FROM Product pm`" in the outer apply?

I cannot always `INNER JOIN @FreeText` because sometimes we don't use free text searching.

Any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated, also let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I do know that MS SQL has a FREETEXT() search, but I unfortunately cannot use that at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, it works quite well, if you have another suggestion, I'd love to hear it... (I know about SQL's FREETEXT() Search, but can't go with that right now).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query without OUTER APPLY, that returns all results when there are no search critera.

```
DECLARE @FreeText TABLE
(
  [text] varchar(200)
)
INSERT INTO @FreeText SELECT 'a'
INSERT INTO @FreeText SELECT 'c'

-- what, null?  No.
DELETE FROM @FreeText WHERE [text] is null

DECLARE @WordCount int
SET @WordCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM @FreeText)

SELECT p.ID
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN @FreeText ft
ON p.txt like '%' + ft.text + '%'
WHERE ft.text is not null OR @WordCount = 0
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = @WordCount OR @WordCount = 0
```

Note: it would be my preference to not use the "freetext" query when there is not any freetext criteria - instead use another query (simpler).  If you choose to go that route - go back to an `INNER JOIN` and drop the `OR @WordCount = 0` x2.

Comment: So, if you're saying not to use the "freetext" query when there is no freetext criteria, you're either talking about creating multiple queries to call, or building dynamic SQL, right? Unfortunately given the nature of the other elements in the entire process, I can't go down those roads (I actually converted this from dynamic SQL some time ago).

I think in the midst of all of my tweaking I lost sight of the left join. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have to profile the two!

Comment: Actually, I just remembered why I can't do a left join - I can't afford the row multiplication result of that join. The benefit of the outer apply is that I don't multiply out rows, and it ends up keeping the query quite expeditious. If you have any other thoughts or suggestions, I would appreciate it!

Comment: The GroupBy deals with that row multiplication issue.  Each ID is unique in the result.

Comment: From these results, and my experiences, it seems that whenever I do row multiplication, my query slows down. I actually have a few of these outer applys in the same query because they avoid any row multiplication. Even with the group by at the end, any row multiplication can have a negative side affect. Going from my version to yours resulted in an increase from 4 seconds to 14 seconds. If you have any other thoughts, I'd love to hear!